# In the linux_dirent64 structs written in the Linux syscall getdents64, why is d_off not the sum of the d_reclens of all earlier entries?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, manpage

According [the man page of getdents](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html):

> `d_off` is the distance from the start
> of the directory to the start of the next `linux_dirent`.  `d_reclen`
> is the size of this entire `linux_dirent`.

So I would expect that if the first entry has `d_reclen` *n*, its `d_off` would also be *n* (and for the *i*-th entry, `d_off` would be the sum of the `d_reclen`s of all entries from *0* to *i*, inclusive).

However, in that same man page, a nicely printed table with the entries of an example directory looks like this:

> ```
>        --------------- nread=120 ---------------
>        inode#    file type  d_reclen  d_off   d_name
>               2  directory    16         12  .
>               2  directory    16         24  ..
>              11  directory    24         44  lost+found
>              12  regular      16         56  a
>          228929  directory    16         68  sub
>           16353  directory    16         80  sub2
>          130817  directory    16       4096  sub3
> ```

The `d_off` fields of the entries do not seem to follow the rule as I expected.
If the first entry has size 16, surely the offset from the start to the second entry would be 16, but apparently it's actually 12.

So what don't I understand about the `d_off` field of `linux_dirent64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained vaguely in the manual page, but as you can probably see by compiling and running the example program, your assumption does not hold.

[The manual page for `readdir(3)`](https://manned.org/readdir.3) gives a bit more insight:

```
d_off  The value returned in d_off is the same as would be returned by
       calling telldir(3) at the current position in the directory
       stream.  Be aware that despite its type and name, the d_off field
       is seldom any kind of directory offset on modern filesystems.
       Applications should treat this field as an opaque value, making no
       assumptions about its contents; see also telldir(3).
```

The key part is *"the `d_off` field is seldom any kind of directory offset on modern filesystems"*. The `d_off` field is a value for internal use by the underlying filesystem, and its meaning is implementation-specific. It does **not** necessarily have any correlation with `d_reclen`, nor does it need to represent an actual "offset" in memory. *Whatever software you write, you should not rely on the value of `d_off` and consider it like an opaque identifier.*

There may be filesystems where `d_off` corresponds to an actual offset in bytes between dirents, but this is in general not the case. The field is used more or less like a unique "counter" or "cookie" value to distinguish files inside a directory.

In fact, if you take a look at the values on a [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/) filesystem, `d_off` seems to start at `1` for `.` and `2` for `..`, increasing by one for any following `dirent`, with the last one having `d_off` equal to `INT32_MAX`. At least for a directory with fresh newly created files, things will change after deleting/moving/creating more files.

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ touch a b c d e f
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 gen 15 01:20 a
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 gen 15 01:20 b
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 gen 15 01:20 c
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 gen 15 01:20 d
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 gen 15 01:20 e
-rw-r----- 1 marco marco 0 gen 15 01:20 f

$ ../test_program
--------------- nread=192 ---------------
inode#    file type  d_reclen  d_off   d_name
46206659  directory    24          1  .
  214242  directory    24          2  ..
46206662  regular      24          3  a
46206663  regular      24          4  b
46206664  regular      24          5  c
46206665  regular      24          6  d
46206666  regular      24          7  e
46206667  regular      24 2147483647  f
```

---

[This 2004 Sourceware bug report for Glibc](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14) by Dan Tsafrir also contains some insightful explanations about `d_off`, such as:

> - In the implementation of `getdents()`, the `d_off` field (belonging to the   linux kernel's `dirent` structure) is falsely assumed to contain
>   the *byte*   offset to the next `dirent`.   Note that the linux manual
>   of the `readdir` system-call states that `d_off`   is the "offset to
>   *this* `dirent`" while glibc's `getdents` treats it as the   offset to the *next* `dirent`.
> - In practice, both of the above are wrong/misleading. The `d_off` field   may contain illegal negative values, 0 (should also never
>   happen as the   "next" `dirent`'s offset must always be bigger then 0),
>   or positive values   that are bigger than the size of the
>   directory-file itself:
>
>   - We're not sure what the Linux kernel intended to place in this
>     field,
>     but our experience shows that on "real" file systems (that actually
>     reside on some disk) the offset seems to be a simple (not necessarily
>     continuous) counter: e.g. first entry may have `d_off=1`, second: `d_off=2`,
>     third: `d_off=4096`, fourth=`d_off=4097` etc. We conjecture this is the
>     serial of the `dirent` record within the directory (and so, this is indeed
>     the "offset", but counted in records out of which some were already
>     removed).
>   - For file systems that are maintained by the amd automounter
>     (automount,
>     directories) the `d_off` seems to be arbitrary (and may be negative, zero
>     or beyond the scope of a 32bit integer). We conjecture the amd doesn't
>     assign this field and the received values are simply garbage.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. So I would say the documentation of this field in the man page for `getdents` is wrong, and inconsistent within that page. I would submit a PR to change the documentation, but I don't know what would be the correct documentation. It seems to me this field could just be removed altogether. But I guess we can't change a syscall's interface just like that.

Comment: @talz the correct way to document that is to make it clear that 1) it is not an offset and 2) it is an internal value that should be relied upon and fs-implementation-specific, used by fs code to identify dirents inside a directory.

Comment: Correction to my previous content: it should **not** be relied upon.

Comment: Someone sent a patch for the manual page: <https://lore.kernel.org/linux-man/SCZPR80MB71490A2B475CBC153A5B3776FC4F2@SCZPR80MB7149.lamprd80.prod.outlook.com/T/#u>.